# Handle system print dialog box in Windows and auto press print button

Tags: google-chrome, printing, handle

Unfortunately Chrome do not have pure silent print(Firefox is not a option) so there is some annoying ~1 sec splash screen in Chrome when you add --kiosk-printing. I have an idea if we add this parameter: --disable-print-preview to Chrome and system print dialog box appear is there any tool that can run in background and click Print button for you so fast that you will not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that can out-of-the-box solve your problem, however, I think it would be easy to develop a small piece of software which does that.

If you are on Windows, then I would recommend using the MS [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) framework to [detect the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748252%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Types_of_Events) when the print dialog box opens and press the "Print" button.

There are also a few free tools that can help you during your development:

- > [Inspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Inspect.exe) is a Windows-based tool that enables you select
  >   any UI element and view the element's accessibility data. You can view
  >   Microsoft UI Automation properties and control patterns, as well as
  >   Microsoft Active Accessibility properties. Inspect also enables you to
  >   test the navigational structure of the automation elements in the UI
  >   Automation tree, and the accessible objects in the Microsoft Active
  >   Accessibility hierarchy.
- > The [Accessible Event Watcher (AccEvent) tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows developers and
  >   testers to validate that an application's UI elements raise proper
  >   Microsoft UI Automation and Microsoft Active Accessibility events when
  >   UI changes occur. Changes in the UI can occur the focus changes, or
  >   when a UI element is invoked, selected, or has a state or property
  >   change.
- > The [AccScope tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn433239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enables developers and testers to evaluate the
  >   accessibility of their app during the app's development and design,
  >   rather than in the late testing phases of an app's development cycle.
  >   Testing can even start in early prototype phases. AccScope can
  >   visualize how a screen reader exposes the UI Automation information
  >   that an app provides, and can show areas where you might want to add
  >   info or support to your app to improve its accessibility.

I've just used Inspect to detect the print dialog box and its "Print" button after it pop-up up. Using these tools you can also find out which event to listen for when the dialog pop-up and then you're all set to develop your program which presses Print.